# how to get numbers from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have

```
"id": 1468306
```

inside of a string, how can I use regular expression to get the number 1468306 for it?

Comment: You need to use a JSON parser.

Comment: @SLaks Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: @user1926122 : If you find answer is correct, Please accept it so that it can help other users in future and it is least you can do for someone spend efforts in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/: (\d+)/
```

as in:

```
s = '"id": 1468306';
r = /: (\d+)/;
console.log(r.exec(s)[1]);
```

Output:

> 1468306

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.parse("{" + yourString + "}").id
```

Will be your number if you have that in a String.

Comment: Not without braces around the string it won't.

Comment: But '"id": 1468306' is not in a string which is like JSON, It's in a in an raw html.

Comment: This string is substring of another string, not sure it's a json string

Comment: Yes you do need braces around the string. And what did you mean, OP? Didn't you say it was a string?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SfeMh/

```
var regEx   = /\d+/g;
var str = '"id": 1468306';
var numbers = str.match(regEx);
alert(numbers); // returns 1468306
```

It looks like you're trying to parse a JSON String. Try this way as already mentioned:

```
var parsedObj = JSON.parse(myJSONString);
alert(parsedObj.id); // returns 1468306
```

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that it's JSON? And why do you think `parseInt` would work here?

Comment: The first example will set `numbers` to an array containing one element: the string `'1468306'`. That it appears to be the number `1468306` is an artifact of how `alert` works.

Comment: @user2736012 because it looks like a JSON string. It doesn't have to, but could be and it would be too bad if he would try to get the contents by regEx instead of the simple parsing. You're right about parseInt.

Comment: @TedHopp good advice, but he asked for a regEx to separate the numbers from the string. If he needs the numbers for calculating, he could/should parse it to a number.

Answer (score 0):

you can use parseInt() method in javascript as follows:

```
var str = parseInt(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code may help you:

```
var input = '"id": 1468306';
var matches = input.match(/"id": (\d+)/);
var id = matches[1];
```

The id get the required number.

Answer (score 0):

This will match in this cases

```
id : 156454;
id :156454;
id:156454;

 /id\s?[:]\s?[0-9]+/g.match(stringhere)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, my JSON answer still stands, use it if that's your full string you're giving us in the question. But if you really want a regex, here's one that will search for "id" and then find the number after.

```
parseInt(yourString.match(/("id"\s?:\s?)(\d+)/)[2])
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tS9M4/